# What's the difference between typedef char[4] A and typedef char (&A)[4]?

Tags: c++, typedef

What's the difference between

```
typedef char[4] A;
```

and

```
typedef char (&A)[4];
```

?

Now I'm just trying to meet post quality standards by writing at least one complete sentence, since my question was already clear at the title.

Comment: The first won't compile - it's gibberish. The second one will - it's a legal typedef. That's the difference.

Comment: Do you mean `typedef char A[4];` in the first one?

Comment: Hang on, but I can do `using A = char[4];`. So why wouldn't the first one work?

Comment: Because of C's confusing inside-out declarator syntax,  compare it to declaring an array variable, which is `char foo[4]` not `char[4] foo`. The new `using` syntax works differently, with alias on the left and type on the right, not jumbled together.

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef char[4] A;
```

This is an invalid attempt to declare a typedef for an array.

```
typedef char (&A)[4];
```

This declares a typedef for *a reference to* an array, which is not the same as an array.

To make the first one valid it should be `typedef char A[4];` but that's still a typedef for an array, which is still different to the second one.